# Excel: Date formatting 'YYYY-MM-DD' after being selected not showing correctly in concatenation

Tags: excel, date, string-formatting

I've copied data into Excel from a SQL database. The way the data is formatted before it gets copied over is: `YYYY-MM-DD`

After it gets copied over, it shows in excel as `M/DD/YYYY`.

I right-clicked the column and selected **Format Cells** to a custom format just as I needed.

The problem is that if I select the value, although the spreadsheet shows the value I need, the actual value itself is different (I'll include a screenshot to show what I'm seeing):

[image: Excel shows different date formats when selected]

My end goal is to select an empty cell and do a simple formula which is:

```
=" DateValue="&B1&" "
```

But it outputs something completely different. Example: If my date was `2016-09-23` or just as it shows above in the image, when applying the formula above, I get:

```
DateValue=42636
```

When what I need is :

```
DateValue=2016-09-23
```

Can anyone advise how to achieve this end goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=" DateValue="&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&" "
```

[image]

It does not matter what the format of **B1** is.  You force the desired format in the **C1** formula.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest `TEXT` function within `CONCAT` function. Text function returns the text in the desired format, and concat function concatenates strings. Following formula will convert the date in cell A1 to the desired output:
 `=CONCAT("DateValue=", TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd"))`